# Create a sound consisting of multiple notes (frequencies)

Tags: .net, vb.net, audio

There are many questions on this site asking how to create a simple sine wave at a given frequency. What I'd like to do is take an array or list or whatever of frequencies and play them smoothly together in a row (not a chord), sounding kind of like the PC Speaker of old. I have tried using `Console.Beep`, but it produces an unacceptable pause between the tones.

I will use NAudio if necessary, but I'd like to avoid third-party libraries.

Comment: If you know how to create a sine wave with a certain frequency, what is stopping you from adding several waves together?

Comment: The title of your post indicates that you want to play chords, i.e. `Console.Beep` different frequencies from several threads simultaneously. Is that your goal?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write the sound waves to a .wav file. Not necessary a file on a disc, but some sound wav array in memory, so that you can play them back later.

Playing the sounds one by one in code, as you have noted, have synchronization problems. The current thread has to wait until the sound finishes before it plays the next sound. If the sounds are already compiled together before they're played then you're only playing one sound, so there's no delay.

As for technically how to do it, a the sound portion of a .wav file is no more simple than a byte array. If you already know how to play a sine wave, with a little research, you should be able to figure the exact bits out without any libraries.